# String.getBytes("ISO-8859-1") gives me 16-bit characters on OS X

Tags: java, macos, unicode, ascii

Using Java 6 to get 8-bit characters from a String:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("öä".getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
```

gives me, on Linux: [-10, 28]
but OS X I get: [63, 63, 63, -89]

I seem get the same result when using the fancy new nio CharSetEncoder class. What am I doing wrong? Or is it Apple's fault? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to reproduce this problem by saving the source file as UTF-8, then telling the compiler it was really MacRoman:

`javac -encoding MacRoman Test.java`

I would have thought `javac` would default to UTF-8 on OSX, but maybe not.  Or maybe you're using an IDE and *it's* defaulting to MacRoman.  Whatever the case, you have to make it use UTF-8 instead.

Comment: It seems MacRoman is the default encoding on my OSX system. The source file with this literal is encoded in UTF-8 and it incorrectly parses it as MacRoman. So how to fix this? Specifying -encoding UTF-8 doesn't seem like a good option. What if I have some good old ISO-8859-1 files in there?

Comment: If some of your files are ISO-8859-1, you'll have to compile them separately anyway and specify *that* encoding.  I suggest you always specify UTF-8, both for saving and compiling.  If a MacRoman or ISO-8859-1 file sneaks in, you'll know about it when compilation fails; it's a lot harder to trick UTF-8 into accepting bogus data than it is most other encodings.

Comment: I figured it would switch to ISO-8859-1 if it couldn't read a file as UTF-8. But that doesn't seem to be the case on my Linux box. So '-encoding utf-8' gives the same behavior. I still don't feel entirely comfortable about using this switch, but I realize I will have to to fix it on my OSX box and similar systems.


I can't help but wonder if there isn't a global "fix" so my system won't explode next time I run into a project that uses UTF-8 string literals and I don't have a unit test to catch the problem?

Comment: The platform-default encoding is one of Java's dirty little secrets; it's *never* safe to rely on it.  The global fix you're looking for is to always specify an encoding when you save and compile source files.  And that encoding might as well be UTF-8, since it can handle every character known to Unicode and it's guaranteed to be supported on every platform.

Answer (score 2):

What is the encoding of the source file? `63` is the code for `?` which means "character can't be converted to the specified encoding".

So my guess is that you copied the source file to the Mac and that the source file uses an encoding which the Mac java compiler doesn't expect. IIRC, OS X will expect the file to be UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

Your source file is producing "öä" by combining characters.

Look at this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("\u00F6\u00E4".getBytes("ISO-8859-1")))
```

This shall print [-10,-28] like you expect (I don't like to print it this way but I know it's not the point of your question), because there the Unicode codepoints are specified, carved in stone, and your text editor is not allowed to "play smart" by combining 'o' and 'a' with diacritic signs.

Typically, when you encounter such problems you probably want to use two OS X Un*x commmands to figure what's going on under the hood: `file` and `hexdump` are very convenient in such cases.

You want to run them on your source file and you may want to run them on your class file.

Comment: Useful little tools. So how come javac doesn't know that this is a UTF-8 file?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the character set for the source is not set (and thus different according to system locale)?

Can you run the same compiled class on both systems (not re-compile)?

Comment: That's most definitely the case. That code, compiled correctly, will produce the same output on all supported platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that there's more than one way to represent characters. Mac OS X uses unicode by default, so your string literal may actually not be represented by two bytes. You need to make sure that you load the string from the appropriate incoming character set; for example, by specifying in the source a \u escape character.

Comment: For what it's worth, an accented character can be represented in two ways; as a single glyph (&ouml;) or as a combining character (\u0308 o).

Comment: Well, in this case the Java file is generated code. Changing the way these characters are encoded in the literal is not feasible.